# Architecture for a Codeigniter Based application

Tags: php, codeigniter, architecture

I am looking at suitable architecture for a Codeigniter based application , the requirement is such that end of the program I must be able to reuse certain modules , completely.

I was looking at a solution like [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home).

I need to know if this is the best solution for my problem.

To build a set of independent modules that can be reused with minimal changes.

Regards,

Gayan

Comment: I'm afraid the "requirement" is way too vague.

Comment: @leonbloy thanks for the tip i will amend accordingly

Comment: I found the answer to this form 

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

"Q. Is Modular Extensions HMVC the same as Modular Separation?

A. Yes and No. Like Modular Separation, Modular Extensions makes modules “portable” to other installations. For example, if you make a nice self-contained model-controller-view set of files you can bring that MVC into another project by copying just one folder - everything is in one place instead of spread around model, view and controller folders."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At what level do you want to reuse "modules"? For example, the models that you create could be reused on a different web application, since they will simply be an interface between your web application and the back-end database.

If you create REST web methods using a framework such as [CodeIgniter REST Server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), those methods might also be at a suitable level of generality that they could be re-used as well.

I suppose the next question is, do you need and entire 'module' of code that can be copied out of this app and pasted into another one? If that is what you are looking for, then HMVC would be the final piece of the puzzle that you can use to tie everything together - just create this general code within one or more modules.

Does that help at all?